# RGB regex with named groups in JS

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to compose a regexp in JS for RGB color string with optional opacity value. To get the data for each channel and opacity I am capturing named groups.

Everything works as intended, but there is something strange for me. When the "B" value in range [200-255], the last digit always goes to opacity group...

For example:

`rgb 195 230 199` -> r: 195, g: 230, b: 199 (All is fine)

`rgb 195 230 199 0.25` -> r: 195, g: 230, b: 199, opacity: 0.25 (All is fine)

`rgb 195 230 200` -> r: 195, g: 230, b: 20, opacity: 0 (Not fine)

And this strange behavior works the same for range 200-255. And spend literally and hour trying to solve it, please, I need some help.

The full regexp is:

```
^(?:rgb|rgba)?[\s+\/]*\(?[\s+\/]*(?<r>[01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])[\s+\/]+(?<g>[01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])[\s+\/]+(?<b>[01]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?:\s)?(?<opacity>0\.\d{1,2}|[1-9]\d{0,1}(?!\d)|100|0|1)??(?:\%)?\)?$
```

Broken into parts:

```
^
(?:rgb|rgba)?
[\s+\/]*
\(?
[\s+\/]*
(?<r>[01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])
[\s+\/]+
(?<g>[01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])
[\s+\/]+
(?<b>[01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])
(?:\s)?
(?<opacity>0\.\d{1,2}|[1-9]\d{0,1}(?!\d)|100|0|1)??
(?:\%)?
\)?
$
```

Comment: You could add a word boundary before the opacity group, and shorten the pattern a bit `^(?:rgba?)?[\s\/]*\(?[\s\/]*(?<r>[01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])[\s\/]+(?<g>[01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])[\s+\/]+(?<b>[01]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\s?\b(?<opacity>0\.\d{1,2}|[1-9]\d?(?!\d)|100|0|1)?%?\)?$` https://regex101.com/r/9dxpVj/1

Comment: Those 4 lines of regex you could've spent for some `.match()` / `.split()`/`.join()` and save a handful of CPU cycles.

Comment: Or you could also make the opacity part with the leading space optional https://regex101.com/r/oXJqCp/1

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov Yes, you are definitely right. I have to do this way because I build up a lot of regular expressions programmatically from "common" parts to make it readable. At least I think so :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the last part you are matching an optional whitespace char `(?:\s)?`

This value will not match *rgb 195 230 200* if the whitespace char is not optional.

But as it is optional it can match **20** in the `<b>` group from the alternation and match **0** in the `<opacity>` group from that alternation.

---

You could either place a word boundary before the opacity group, or make the group optional.

```
^(?:rgba?)?[\s\/]*\(?[\s\/]*(?<r>[01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])[\s\/]+(?<g>[01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])[\s+\/]+(?<b>[01]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(?: (?<opacity>0\.\d{1,2}|[1-9]\d?(?!\d)|100|0|1)?%?)?\)?$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oXJqCp/1)

Note that the pattern can be shortened a bit by omitting superfluous groups and escapes like `(?:\%)?`and using `?` which is the same as `{0,1}`

In this part `[\s+\/]*` the pattern allows matching a `+` character instead of repeating the `\s` 1 or more times because it is a character class. If that is not the intention, you can omit the `+`

Comment: I didn't know I can do that with named group. Thank you for help and making my regexp better! You saved me a lot of time and gave me some knowledge, thank you!